# Different style for tables HTML

Tags: html, css, html-table

I got a Wordpress template which has a basic style for tables:

```
table {
    border-collapse:separate;
    border-spacing:0;
    margin-bottom:30px;
    margin-top:30px;
    width:100%;
}

table, td, th {
    vertical-align:middle;
    line-height: 30px;
    border: 2px solid #EDEBE5;
}

th {
    color:#585D63;
    font-family:Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:normal;
    text-align:center;
    line-height: 50px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    background-color: #EDEBE5;
    font-style:italic;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px #BBBBBB;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1px #BBBBBB;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px #BBBBBB;
}

td {
    color:#585D63;
    font-family:Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:normal;
    text-align:center;
    line-height: 50px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-style:italic;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #EDEBE5;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px #bbbbbb;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1px #bbbbbb;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px #bbbbbb;
}
```

Now my customer wants me to create a basic table for contact information. But whenever I create a table it automatically uses the style listed below with the background and border.

Now I gave my table a different class like

```
<table class="contacttbl">

 <tr>
   <td class="contacttd">Telefoon:</td>
   <td class="contacttd">+31 (0) 000000000000</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td class="contacttd">Telefoon:</td>
   <td class="contacttd">000000000000</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td class="contacttd">Telefoon:</td>
   <td class="contacttd">+31 (0) 000000000000</td>
 </tr>

</table>
```

And style:

```
.contacttbl{
   width:300px;
   border:0px;
}

.contacttd{
   text-align:left;
   border:0px;
   background-color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

This all works fine beside one thing. I still get the border while I did `border:0px;` How can it be that my custom table copies all style rules, but not the border?..

Comment: a good process for figuring this stuff out is to "inspect element" with the build in developer tools, and uncheck associated styles until you find the ones causing the style you're trying to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually not a border but a `box-shadow`.

```
.contacttd{
    text-align:left;
    border:0px;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
}
```

This does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

On the original CSS `td` and `th` have a border, but you haven't added these to the new CSS class called contacttbl. Add `td` and `th` with a border of 0px;

For example, to sort out the `td`s:

```
.contacttbl td {
border:0px;
}
```

Comment: I did add the td .contacttd. I didnt did the th. but I sint using that in my table. so it shouldnt be used right?

Comment: It was actually a border shadow. very stupid of me. thank you for helping me anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `border-collapse` as follows

```
.contacttbl{
    width:300px;
    border:0px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Comment: it was actually the box shadow. thanx for helping anyway!

Comment: @Merijndk I think I misread your question, I thought you wanted to eliminate the borders

Comment: No problems, glad you got it sorted!

Comment: yeah I wanted. But the borders ended up to be a box shadow. very stupid. but it is fixed now!